# How to match url pattern in tornado such as www.abc.com/?code=abcd1234

Tags: url, tornado

I've googled a lot but cannot find.

For example, my app is www.abc.com, how can I match this kind of url:

```
www.abc.com/?code=abcd1234
```

My handlers:

```
handers = [
  (r"/?", HomeHandler),
  (r"/?code=([^/]+)", OtherHandler),
]
```

the second pattern is wrong I think, and it always use the first

Comment: So stupid I am, I've know that r"/" is path and  ?code=([^/]+) is query. FYI, [link](http://webpy.org/cookbook/url_handling)

Comment: Now that you've solved your issue, you should create an answer and accept it http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I know that r"/" is path and '?code=([^/]+)' is query.